# What does the android:configChanges="screenSize" attribute do?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I would like to know what the above mentioned **attribute** for an `Activity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` does and why it (would be) needed?

I have already read the Android documentation about this topic and the explaination is not quite clear to me. Id like to know an example case **WHY** I would have to set this attribute.

Comment: *The current available screen size has changed. This represents a change in the currently available size, relative to the current aspect ratio, so will change when the user switches between landscape and portrait*

Comment: Taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Comment: Thank you, I already read the docs. Unfortunately it's not quite clear to me what it does.

Comment: it calls onConfigurationChanged if the screen size changes

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you may have known every time a parameter of the phone changes the system rebuilds the whole Activity in order to load the new resources. On of these parameters is the screen size, which can change on a phone, as the rotation of the phone changes it.

If you define `android:configChanges` in your manifest you can have full control over your application, which means that the system won't destroy your Activity, it only calls the `onConfiguratinChanged` method of it. This way you have to manage the resizeing of the screen.

Comment: Allright, thank you. Does this mean if I am using a CustomView inside my Activity that is dependant on the screen size, and I set this attribute, the size of the CustomView does not adjust upon orientation change?

Comment: If its width/height set to match_parent/fill_parent it will be resized, but the content won't be redrawn with the new sizes

Comment: Thank you, thats all I needed to know.