# What does "android:configChanges" do?

Tags: android

I was creating an app that supports pip mode. I came across `android:configChanges`. What does it do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the android:configChanges="screenSize" attribute do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120903/what-does-the-androidconfigchanges-screensize-attribute-do)

Comment: perhaps also relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation

Comment: `android:configChanges="smallestScreenSize|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"`, what does this do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Android, when device configuration changes (such as users rotate the screen orientation, change language, etc..), the system will restart the running Activity (`onDestroyed()` is called, followed by `onCreate()`) to apply the new configuration.

If your application doesn't want this behavior to happen (maybe you don't want to restart the running activity or you want to apply the new configuration by yourself), then you can declare that the activity will handle the configuration by itself which preventing the system from restarting the activity.

To do that you go to the AndroidManifest.xml file, find the appropriate `<activity>` tag,  add the  `android:configChanges` attribute with a value that represents the configuration you want to handle.

Now when the configuration changes, the system does not restart your activity. Instead your activity will receive a call to `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method along with the new configuration.

You should go to [activity-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element), read the "android:configChanges" section, you will understand it clearly. By the way, Android provides documentation about how to handle configuration changes in runtime [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes).