How to programmatically rotate a Jetpack Compose screen to landscape and back to portrait without restarting the activity?
I am working on a single-activity Android app using Jetpack Compose, where the activity is restricted to portrait mode in the manifest file. I want to programmatically rotate the screen to landscape when needed and then return to portrait mode when the back button is pressed, all without restarting the activity or causing a recomposition.
Since the activity is locked to portrait mode, how can I handle this rotation in Compose?
Any guidance or examples would be appreciated!
I tried the following code to switch to landscape:
(context as Activity).requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE

And this code to switch back to portrait:
(context as Activity).requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED


Provided lines of code in the question are doing the needful but there is problem that it restart the activity but I don't want to restart activity.

Why do you need to avoid any activity restarts? Your app should generally be implemented to handle orientation changes well. If you use ViewModels, rememberSaveable etc. then Activity recreation should not be a problem.

As app is built on a single activity, there are some flags locally in the activity. Therefore I want to avoid activity recreation.

Have you tried setting the configChanges attribute in the manifest.xml? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65182773/what-does-androidconfigchanges-do

Initially, I tried using android:configChanges="orientation", but it didn’t work. Then, I tried android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize", and it worked fine. Now the screen orientation changes without activity recreation. However, are there any potential issues that may arise from preventing the activity from being recreated?

Avoid restarting the activity
Developers have limited control over an activity lifecycle. The android system can and will destroy and recreate your activity "at will", e.g. when rotating the screen or when it needs memory and your app is in the background.
Therefore, your app needs to be designed in a way that it can handle activity recreation.
Thankfully, android(x) offers multiple solutions for storing data beyond the activity lifecycle depending on your usage scenario:

In case your data is rather scoped to the whole Application, move it into a custom Application class.

In case your data is scoped to the screen you've got at least two options depending on the amount of data:

use composes rememberSavable for small amounts of data, see docs
use a ViewModel for more complex data & operations: In fact, the viewModel documentation mentions surviving screen rotations as a primary benefit: "This means that your UI doesn’t have to fetch data again [...] when rotating the screen."




Avoid causing a recomposition
One of the primary mechanics of Compose is (re)composition. It can occur as often as every frame, see docs. Make sure to structure your code in such a way that this is no issue, or you won't b having fun in compose!

Programatically rotate a screen in compose
I believe your code actually is correct, but you might want to compare it to a known working sample:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73620102/12871582
